# Eclipse ADT removes permissions when signing APK

Tags: java, android, permissions, adt

I am using Eclipse ADT to sign my app for submission to the Play Store.  I right click on the project and choose Android Tools -> Export Signed Application Package.  However when I do this  it removes permissions from the Manifest file that is required for the application to run.  Below is my Manifest file.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.myou.MyApp"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

After exporting the uses-permission is removed:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I have tried fixing the properties in the Android Tools before exporting, but it still removes the permission.

Comment: why you don't use manifest file to export `APK`?

Comment: How are you determining that this has been removed?

Comment: I see that the permissions have been removed when I open the manifest file and when I run the apk it doesn't have the permissions to run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone comes across this problem the simple answer is:

Do not attempt to edit `AndroidManifest.xml` file found in the `bin` directory. You need to change the file in the root of your project.

Comment: Yes, took me a while to work this out, but I did.  Should have answered my own question.

Answer (score 0):

try restarting eclipse and then exporting your application.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Will try when I'm back at work.